# Parsing string data stored all in one column and then pivoting information into separate columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am pulling a report from a database that stores the equivalent of a form all in one string column. The form has the same section headings every single time. I have converted these column headings to "|" and would then like to use that as a delimiter to put the respective responses in separate columns. I have the pivot accomplished, but then entire result is repeating in each column rather than parsing correctly. Sample column text with eventual column headers in bold **.

I feel like I need to change my partition statement and include a case when and then change the '|' to 1, 2, 3, etc.

**Community Health Worker Initial Outreach**    XYZ is an 48 y.o. female contacted on 99/99/19.    **Reason for Outreach:**  This writer called due to XYZ      **Referral Source:**   CCM NCM    Initial Contact/Status:   Agreed to Enrollment    **Was 7 day follow-up with PCP scheduled:**   NO    **Do you need assistance with transportation to the PCP office:**   No    **Identified Issues or Concerns:**

```
WITH C AS(

SELECT DISTINCT hnt.note_id, hnt.line,  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
(note_text, 'CHW Initial Contact/Status:', 'Initial Status'),'Community Health Worker Initial Outreach', '|'), 'Reason for Outreach:', '|')
, 'Referral Source:', '|'), 'Initial Contact/Status:', '|'), 'Was 7 day follow-up with PCP scheduled:','|'),'Do you need assistance with transportation to the PCP office:','|'),
'Identified Issues or Concerns:','|') as field  , row_number () over (partition by hnt.note_id order by hnt.contact_date desc) rn        
From hno_note_text hnt
inner join       note_smartphrase_ids    nsi on hnt.NOTE_CSN_ID = nsi.NOTE_CSN_ID

CROSS APPLY string_split(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
(note_text, 'CHW Initial Contact/Status:', 'Initial Status'),'Community Health Worker Initial Outreach', '|'), 'Reason for Outreach:', '|')
, 'Referral Source:', '|'), 'Initial Contact/Status:', '|'), 'Was 7 day follow-up with PCP scheduled:','|'),'Do you need assistance with transportation to the PCP office:','|'),
'Identified Issues or Concerns:','|') , '|')    as separated
where smartphrases_id = '151325'    and hnt.line = '1' 
)
SELECT  note_id,
 [1] AS Initial_Outreach
      ,[2] AS Reason
      ,[3] AS RefSource
      ,[4] AS Contact_Status
      ,[5] AS SevenDay
      ,[6] AS Transportation
      ,[7] AS Issues
FROM C
PIVOT(
    MAX(field)
    FOR RN IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])  
) as PVT
```

--Based on suggested changes, modified code to (I have no idea why the last part of revised code is not showing!):

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID varchar(254), YourString VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable 
select distinct hnt.note_id, note_text
From hno_note_text hnt
inner join note_smartphrase_ids nsi on hnt.NOTE_CSN_ID = nsi.NOTE_CSN_ID
where smartphrases_id = '151325'    and hnt.line = '1' 

SELECT  *
FROM @mockupTable t

CROSS APPLY(SELECT CONCAT('{'
,REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(t.YourString
,'Community Health Worker Initial Outreach','"Initial_Outreach":"')
,'Reason for Outreach:','","Reason":"')
,'Referral Source:','","RefSource":"')
,'Was 7 day follow-up with PCP scheduled:','","SevenDay":"')
,'Do you need assistance with transportation to the PCP                     office:','","Transportation":"')
,' Identified Issues or Concerns:','","Issues":"'), 'ACO PRAPARE Screening  Questionnaire','","PRAPARE":"'),
'Next Steps:','","Next Step":"')
,'"}')) A(CastedToJSON)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.CastedToJSON)
WITH(Initial_Outreach VARCHAR(MAX)
,Reason VARCHAR(MAX)
,RefSource VARCHAR(MAX)
,SevenDay VARCHAR(MAX)
,Transportation VARCHAR(MAX)
,Issues VARCHAR(MAX)
,Prapare VARCHAR(MAX)
,NextSteps VARCHAR(MAX)
) B;
```

Comment: Usually with SQL questions like this, it is helpful to show a small sample of the original data (with bogus values if sensitive), and what you want it to look like. Also helpful to know the flavor of SQL that you're using. Thanks.

Comment: thanks. updated description as requested. use SSMS 2016

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server?

Answer (score 0):

With SQL-Server 2016 (you commented with *SSMS 2016*) I'd suggest to walk along the JSON route:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourString NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES(N'Community Health Worker Initial Outreach XYZ is an 48 y.o. female contacted on 99/99/19. Reason for Outreach: This writer called due to XYZ Referral Source: CCM NCM Initial Contact/Status: Agreed to Enrollment Was 7 day follow-up with PCP scheduled: NO Do you need assistance with transportation to the PCP office: No Identified Issues or Concerns:')

SELECT *
FROM @mockupTable t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CONCAT('{'
                         ,REPLACE(
                          REPLACE(
                          REPLACE(
                          REPLACE(
                          REPLACE(
                          REPLACE(
                          REPLACE(t.YourString
                                 ,'Community Health Worker Initial Outreach','"Initial_Outreach":"')
                                 ,'Reason for Outreach:','","Reason":"')
                                 ,'Referral Source:','","RefSource":"')
                                 ,'Initial Contact/Status:','","Contact_Status":"')
                                 ,'Was 7 day follow-up with PCP scheduled:','","SevenDay":"')
                                 ,'Do you need assistance with transportation to the PCP office:','","Transportation":"')
                                 ,'Identified Issues or Concerns:','","Issues":"')
                         ,'"}')) A(CastedToJSON)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.CastedToJSON)
            WITH(Initial_Outreach NVARCHAR(MAX)
                ,Reason NVARCHAR(MAX)
                ,RefSource NVARCHAR(MAX)
                ,Contact_Status NVARCHAR(MAX)
                ,SevenDay NVARCHAR(MAX)
                ,Transportation NVARCHAR(MAX)
                ,Issues NVARCHAR(MAX)
                ) B;
```

The intermediate JSON looks like this one:

```
{
    "Initial_Outreach": " XYZ is an 48 y.o. female contacted on 99/99/19. ",
    "Reason": " This writer called due to XYZ ",
    "RefSource": " CCM NCM ",
    "Contact_Status": " Agreed to Enrollment ",
    "SevenDay": " NO ",
    "Transportation": " No ",
    "Issues": ""
}
```

The idea in short:

- We use some string methods to transform your string into a JSON string
- we use `OPENJSON` to get into the JSON and
- we use a `WITH`-clause to return the result in columns (implicit pivoting)

Hint: The result might need some trimming...

Comment: @agalgay *as follows...*?

Comment: sorry....had a heck of a time posting the revised code in original post

Comment: @agalgay, Ah, I see... Just one hint: I corrected my answer a little bit, the code you cite is not the last one... And one more: This is not how SO works. There is no need to fill the answer to the question. The question is - well - a question, and the answer(s) are possible solutions. It is very kind of you to say *Thank you*, but it would be even kinder to tick the acceptance check, if this answer solved your issue. Once you've reached 15 points yourself, you are asked to vote additionally. This helps future researchers to find an answer and this is how to say Thx on SO. Happy Coding

Comment: Yours works with the values, but my values are from a select statement. When I replace your values clause with a select statement, I get the following error: An explicit value for the identity column in table '@mockupTable' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: @agalgay, You have got this slightly wrong. My table `@mockupTable` is just to create a *stand-alone* example to **simulate** your issue. You do not need this at all. You must adopt my code in a way, that replaces `@mockupTable` with your real table's name and all column names the same. There is no need to shift your values into my *mockup* scenario... As a shortcut you can take away the `IDENTITY` after `ID` in my `@mockupTable` declaration. Doing so it might be enough to replace my `VALUES` with your `SELECT`...

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach:

Declare @mocktable Table (field varchar(2000))
Insert Into @mocktable

```
select distinct replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
(note_text, 'CHW Initial Contact/Status:', 'Initial Status'),'Community Health Worker Initial Outreach', '|'), 'Reason for Outreach:', '|')
, 'Referral Source:', '|'), 'Initial Contact/Status:', '|'), 'Was 7 day follow-up with PCP scheduled:','|'),'Do you need assistance with transportation to the PCP office:','|'),
'Identified Issues or Concerns:','|'), 'ACO PRAPARE Screening Questionnaire','|'),
 'Next Steps:','|') as field 
From hno_note_text hnt
inner join note_smartphrase_ids nsi on hnt.NOTE_CSN_ID = nsi.NOTE_CSN_ID
 where smartphrases_id = '151325'   and hnt.line = '1' 
select a.*, b.* from @mocktable   a

Cross Apply (
Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(field,'|','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as B1
) B
```

Comment: Just a warning: This relys on the sort order and existance of all expected fields. A different order or missing element will break this up...